# Parsing HTTP request streams with C++: any not state machine way with same speed or better?

Tags: c++, c, http, parsing

So we have some simple [request](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudClient/src/utils/http/http_request.cpp)/[response](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudClient/src/utils/http/http_response.cpp) parsers. thay are bacically simple state machines that could be esely created in pure C code. I wonder what is C++ way to parse HTTP 1.0+ requesrt/response streams that would be as fast or faster than C analogs yet would be sweeter from code prespective?

Comment: You can look at [Boost::Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio.html) for some ideas on this.

Comment: @user315052: If you look at what he's linked, you'll find that he's apparently already looked at Boost::Asio a bit (i.e., his existing code is already using it).

Comment: You can look at HTTP protocol RFC for some ideas on this. LOL

Comment: Or search google for "sweet C++" ! ?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: He wasn't following the examples of using the asio streambuf to pass to an istream. I suppose I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than coding up explicit state machines, you could probably use [`Spirit.Qi`](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) to build a parser for the data. This generally gives rather slow compilation, but execution that's quite competitive.

You might want to look at a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458173/179910) by @sehe for some inspiration on parsing binary data with Spirit.